# Conditionally reload webpage - Java script

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, reload

I want to reload a web page for every 3 seconds and if some form elements has specific values after reload I want to stop reloading the page and pop up and alert message.

For example in picture below

[image]

Batsmen score will be updated dynamically.

I want to pop-up an alert box when score reaches 50.

I know little bit about `JavaScript` please let me know how I can install such a script in `Firefox`.

I know how to read HTML form element values. Any pseudo code to do this is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/ and then write a GM-script that looks for your values and then refresh the page. I did something similar a few years back and it was really simple with GreaseMonkey.

Answer (score 0):

You don't usually reload the whole page in such scenarios.

You send asynchronous requests to the server & update the page parts as per the response received without refreshing the whole page.

Read about [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). Also you would require server side programming, to respond to those AJAX calls. You have quite some reading to do before you can implement a page as above.

Though [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), isn't a necessity, I would really suggest you to pick it up along.

Answer (score 0):

let us  consider this scenarios , when bat men score are stored 47

after your page finish load call a javscript function to alert.

```
function infoo(){
if(document.getElementById('batmens-1').innerHTML=="50")
{
alert("messabge");
}
}

infoo();// this will be called when page refreshes
setInterval(infoo,1000); //will check when score are updated by ajax and do the alert
```

Comment: How I can add this script in my browser(firefox) for espncricinfo website?

Comment: use scratchpad in developer tools of firefox

Comment: If I paste this script code in scratchpad then will it run for every second if espncricinfo was opened in firefox?Whether the espncricinfo tab should be active?Do I run it manually?Update the steps NOT able to test your code.